# Video and Image Filter Like Instagram in Android

Tags: android, image, filtering, imagefilter, vine

I am developing one application which is required Video and Image filter like Instagram i spend lot of time over Internet i did not find any thing very use full now i am using this code for image filter but response time is very slow .

```
public class LightingFilterPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public static String[] styles = { "No Filter", "Chrome", "Cool", "Classic", "Fade", "Noir", "Greyscale", "Highlight", "Invert", "Snow", "MeanRemova", "SepiaToning" };
private Bitmap originBitmap, filteredBitmap;
private SparseArray<View> selectorArray = new SparseArray<View>();

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public LightingFilterPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setFilterable(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.originBitmap = null == bitmap ? BitmapFactory.decodeResource(layoutInflater.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher) : Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
            150, 150, false);
}

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.35f;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_pager_item, null);

    if (position == 0 || position > styles.length) {
        filteredBitmap = originBitmap;
    } else {
        filteredBitmap = applyStyle(position, originBitmap);
    }

    // initially selected no filter
    View selView = view.findViewById(R.id.selector_v);
    selectorArray.put(position, selView);
    selView.setVisibility(0 == position ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    ImageView filterIv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_iv);
    filterIv.setImageBitmap(filteredBitmap);

    TextView filterTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_tv);
    filterTv.setText(styles[position]);

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // unselect all except selected one
            for (int i = 0; i < selectorArray.size(); i++) {
                View selectorView = selectorArray.get(selectorArray.keyAt(i));
                selectorView.setVisibility(i == position ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            if (null != filterSelectedListener) {
                filterSelectedListener.onFilterSelected(position, styles[position]);
            }
        }
    });

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return null == styles ? 0 : styles.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

private FilterSelectedListener filterSelectedListener;

public void setFilterSelectedListener(FilterSelectedListener listener) {
    this.filterSelectedListener = listener;
}

public interface FilterSelectedListener {
    void onFilterSelected(int position, String name);
}

public interface StyleListener {
    void onStyleApplied(int position, String filter, Bitmap filtered);
}

public static void applyStyleAsync(final Context context, final int position, final Bitmap bitmap, final StyleListener listener) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (null == context || position < 0 || position >= styles.length || null == listener) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments should avoid conditions: (null == context || position < 0 || position >= styles.length || null == listener)");
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Bitmap filtered = position == 0 ? bitmap : applyStyle(position, bitmap);
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listener.onStyleApplied(position, styles[position], filtered);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

/**
 * "No Filter", "Chrome", "Cool", "Classic", "Fade", "Noir"
 * 
 * @param styleNo
 * @param originBitmap
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap applyStyle(int styleNo, Bitmap originBitmap) {
    Bitmap changeBitmap = null;
    switch (styleNo) {
    case 1:
        // changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 1, 1.5f, true);
    //  changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 69, 9, true);
        //changeBitmap=ImageFilters.applyFleaEffect(originBitmap);
        changeBitmap = applyTintFilter(originBitmap, "#FFCC00");
        break;
    case 2:
        changeBitmap = applyTintFilter(originBitmap, "#bfc3ff");
        break;
    case 3:
        changeBitmap = applyTintFilter(originBitmap, "#ffffcc");
        break;
    case 4:
        changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, -30, 0, false);
        break;
    case 5:
        changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 1, 0.05f, true);
        break;
    case 6:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applyGreyscaleEffect(originBitmap);
        break;
    case 7:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applyHighlightEffect(originBitmap);
        break;
    case 8:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applyInvertEffect(originBitmap);
        break;
    case 9:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applySnowEffect(originBitmap);
        break;
    case 10:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applyMeanRemovalEffect(originBitmap);
        break;
    case 11:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applySepiaToningEffect(originBitmap, 1, 21, 20, 255);
        break;
    case 12:
        changeBitmap = ImageFilters.applyDecreaseColorDepthEffect(originBitmap, 5);
        break;
    case 13:
        changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 1, 0.05f, true);
        break;
    case 14:
        changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 1, 0.05f, true);
        break;
    case 15:
        changeBitmap = getFilteredBitmap(originBitmap, 1, 1, 0.05f, true);
        break;
    default:
        changeBitmap = originBitmap;
        break;
    }

    return changeBitmap;
}

private static Bitmap getFilteredBitmap(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness, float saturation, boolean bandw) {
    Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.set(new float[] { contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness, 0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness, 0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
    if (bandw) {
        cm.setSaturation(saturation);
    }
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
    return alteredBitmap;
}

private static Bitmap applyTintFilter(Bitmap bitmap, String htmlColor) {
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(htmlColor), Mode.MULTIPLY);
    paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);

    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: For image filter i found very use full library http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/gpuimage/ but for video filter still i am looking

Comment: For video filter i followed https://www.virag.si/2014/03/playing-video-with-opengl-on-android/   implemented filters on video preview..but still finding a solution to add the filters to the video and save it